# My friends are disrupting my internet connection

Tags: wifi, ip, denial-of-service, internet

My friends have my ip address and they're all programmers/hackers. They've been interfering with my wifi connection several times today. Asking them to stop or saying "they won't do anything" is not an answer since I've tried to tell them to stop but they carried on. What can I do?

Also, I have witnessed them interfering my connection firsthand.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHlOK.png): [image: He even admitted that he has my ip.]

Comment: Them knowing your IP address is unlikely to be of any relevance; they're just saying that because they think it sounds scary. Can you elaborate on "_I have witnessed them interfering my connection firsthand_"?

Comment: Also, you failed at hiding the other person's username

Comment: Okay so basically, my internet stopped and kept being interrupted and I know that it's my friend's doing. They have my ip address because we were playing on a minecraft server and they banned my ip and when they checked the ban ip log in the server configuration, they saw my ip. He coded is own Ip booter and he's an expert when it comes to tech.

Comment: Reboot your router. Your ISP might give you a new IP.